# Como fazer um backup remoto do PostgreSQL salvando o arquivo na minha maquina?

Tags: postgresql, putty

Tenho uma maquina que preciso fazer backup do banco de dado PostgreSQL, ele está em um container docker em um servidor, para fazer o backup tentei o seguinte script:

```
docker exec -t postgresDB pg_dump -U usuario_banco -h remote_host --host=127.0.0.1 --port=5432 nome_do_banco --file=/etc/backup.bkp
```

O problema que é o banco é grande e falta espaço para o backup, gostaria de saber se tem alguma forma de salvar direto na minha maquina.

Answer (score 0):

Você pode usar `docker exec -v {fora_do_container: dentro_do_container}`.

O `-v` serve para criar um volume dentro do docker host, onde você pode salvar os arquivos do banco e ele não é deletado caso você apague o container.

- `fora_do_container`: caminho para a pasta a ser salva fora do container
- `dentro_do_container`: caminho para a pasta que será salva